# quota giving (seemingly) incorrect values

Tags: linux, quota

After some porting and moving of drives and so forth, our new system reports my user account as being well over the quota limit setup.  I am now supposedly using 135GB, but my quota is 21GB.

I can't seem to find where this space is being used, however.

I re-ran quotacheck to update the quota files, which didn't change anything.

The drive mount point is **/home**.

When I check the disk usage on my home directory with **du -s /home/madeleine** I find that I have 2GB of usage in my home dir.  Looking through the home directory with **ls**, I don't find any other directories being owned by me.

So... where is this usage coming from?  It doesn't appear to be my home directory, and I don't see usage anywhere else on the drive.

Can I get a better break down from quota or from another utility?

I have the possibility to elevate to root if need be.

Regards,
Madeleine.

Answer (score 0):

I found a ton of files in a backup directory that an admin had made [and saved in /home/backups].  The ownership of the files was the same, so it counted against my quota.

Here's how I searched.  In this case, I searched the whole file system.  Searching /home would have sufficed for this case.

```
find / -type f -user madeleine -print0 | du -ch --files0-from=- > myFiles.txt
```

Regards, Madeleine